# how to grow height with the amount of text in css?

Tags: html, css, text, height

i have this situation

```html
<div class="sub_project">
    <div class="sbone brown_gradient optzeci">Description</div>
    <div class="sbtwo optzecitwo">
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.sub_project{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #D7D7D7;
}

.brown_gradient{
    background: #EB994F;
}
.sbone{
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;

}

.sbtwo{padding: 5px;}

.optzeci{height: 80px;}
.optzecitwo{min-height: 80px;} * html .optzeci { height:80px; }
```

I would like the `<div class="sbone brown_gradient optzeci">Description</div>` height to grow with the amount of text.

Right now i set a `min-height: 80px;` but i do't want to set height at all.

Also i don't want to use images or javascript

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/W7Nrn/1/)

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "right now i set a `min-height: 80px;` but i do't want to set height at all." Then don't.

Comment: Why do you need to set a height at all? What are you trying to achieve that doesn't work if you just remove the height property?

Comment: I believe you will need javascript for this. Why don't you want to use javascript?

Comment: you're setting the height to 80px with

.optzeci{height: 80px;}

Comment: maybe i didn't express myself clear enough. I need some way that the brownish div to grow with the amount of text.take a look at the example and see what happens if i take the height out

Comment: also the html structure doesnt have to be the same like mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relatively position the container, `.sub_project`, and give it left padding.  Absolutely position `.optzeci` and give it `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/W7Nrn/9/

```
.sub_project {
    ...
    padding-left: 175px;
    position: relative;
}
.optzeci {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can use jquery then you can assign height to the box on the fly. you just need to get the height on the div containing your text then assign the same height to description box.

here is my try: http://jsfiddle.net/W7Nrn/6/

Comment: thanks also for the answer, might come in hand one day, but the person im doing this for is not so found of javascript

Comment: @Lokesh - Then you would also need to add a `window.onresize` handler, since the height of the content will change with the width of the window.

Comment: @gilly3: you are right sir :) your approach to solve this problem with css is mush easier then javascript.